# Login to Amazon with Cookies and Scrape Kindle Highlights

Tags: javascript, python, cookies, fetch

Amazon Kindle has the following site where you can access highlights from your Kindle: from `https://read.amazon.com/notebook`.

I want to scrape these highlights but none of my attempts have worked so far. I know that this should be possible because Readwise does this and a note-taking app named Reflect.app has a chrome extension where they also managed to do this.

I found this URL that returns relevant JSON data with a list of books read (this is the first piece of the puzzle): https://read.amazon.com/kindle-library/search?query=&libraryType=BOOKS&sortType=recency. If I go to the Network tab and copy the request as a cURL and import it on Postman, the request ends up working successfully.

I've tried making the request on the client side with Fetch and Axios and with Python on the backend but neither approach has worked.

When I make the request on the client side, I get the error `Access to fetch at 'https://read.amazon.com/kindle-library/search?query=&libraryType=BOOKS&sortType=recency' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.`

Here is the code I am using, which I got by copying the request on the Network tab as a fetch request:

```
const request = await fetch(
    "https://read.amazon.com/kindle-library/search?query=&libraryType=BOOKS&sortType=recency",
    {
      headers: {
        accept: "*/*",
        "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
        "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
        "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
        "sec-fetch-site": "none",
      },
      referrerPolicy: "strict-origin-when-cross-origin",
      body: null,
      method: "GET",
      mode: "cors",
      credentials: "include",
    }
  );
```

I've tried many iterations of this. For example, I have tried setting the mode to "no-cors" but then I get an empty response. I also tried adding the session cookie information in the header of the request but that doesn't make a difference.

So I tried making the request from the backend using Python and Flask. When I do a get request using the Requests library, the url gets redirected to the amazon login page. I tried adding the session cookie as well and that didn't make a difference.

This is the code I have:

```
@api.route('/data')
def data():
    session = requests.session()
    request_url = 'https://read.amazon.com/kindle-library/search?query=&libraryType=BOOKS&sortType=recency'

    headers = {
        "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
        "cookie": "<cookie session info>"
    }

    params = {
        "referrerPolicy": "strict-origin-when-cross-origin",
    }

    req = session.get(request_url, headers=headers, params=params)
```

I think what I need to do is find a way to authenticate with Amazon when making the request and I believe the way to do that is with a cookie. Right now I am just trying to hardcode my own cookie information but I would need a way to get the cookie from the user's session as well.

I'm not sure what I'm missing here. Or maybe there is a better way to do what I want to do?

Comment: Update: I found this repository (https://github.com/speric/kindle-highlights) and it works but it requires email and password to be entered by the user and I don't want to have to handle user passwords because that's a privacy concern. 

I want to make this work by having the user authenticate through Amazon themselves and use the cookie of their session. Still haven't been able to figure out how to do this with Cookies

Comment: Have you seen [Bookcision](https://readwise.io/bookcision)? It's maintained by Readwise so I'm wondering if they're using some version of this code in their Chrome extension. [Here](https://github.com/TristanH/bookcision)'s the github repo. There is a surprising amount of code in the repo so I'm wondering if scraping the highlights is more complicated than one would think.

Comment: Great find, thanks for sharing @jeffbernst! This looks like it can definitely be helpful for scraping the data but the main thing I am struggling with is authenticating the user with Cookies so that I can get access to read.amazon.com programatically. Once that works, the script in this code could be run on read.amazon.com